# Android - Performance Hit of Including External Jar

Tags: android, library-project

Are there any disadvantages to including an external Jar (e.g. the Admob Codebase) into an app that makes no use of it? I'm creating two versions of the same app, and it appears to be a lot simpler to just include it in both the ad-free and ad-supported.

So, does it simply take up more space on the phone, or does it affect performance of the app?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627492/android-library-project/5627562 where I establish how it's "a lot simpler"

Comment: Have you simply thought of trying this yourself? Build both versions (including the external jar), install them on your phone, check the space used and the performance of each. That should give you your answer without having to ask here.

Comment: Did it. Space went up. But how can I tell if there's a true performance hit? How to benchmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proguard and the android export tool remove any methods, classes, resources, etc. that are not actually linked or used in the project. Methods you yourself have written will be culled if you don't refer to them, so I'd be confident that the same would happen with an external JAR.

If the space free went up with the unreferencing project, then I think it's safe to say the JAR was deemed surplus to requirements and stripped from the export.