# Exclude admob jar from paid version

Tags: android, admob

I'am developing both a free and a paid verion of a application. I have it currently set up as one "android library project" and two regular android projects both refering to the library.

One benefit of my application over the competition is that the size of the apk is quite small. 
I would like too keep the size as small as possible, especially for the paid version.

So how can I keep a common source in the library project and only include the admob jar in the free version of my application?

I found a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627492/android-library-project) mentions that a wrapper would be one possibility. But it dose not specify how you actually would implement the solution.

Comment: I need an answer to this. And that answer link is essentially saying to put a if(LITE){show add} else {hide add} NOT removing the jar file from the actual compiled product. Some android app stores EXPECT no jar files of ads even if ads are disabled. Because of this I can't submit my paid version app to some app stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple when I figured it out.

In the free version you just extend your activity with one that also displays ads. Now only include the jar-file for admob in the ad supported one. And you are set.

```
public class AdNanoMusicActivity extends NanoMusicActivity {

private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.paid)) {
        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a1500167a6bde8a");

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView,0);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

AdNanoMusicActivity extends the NanoMusicActivity which is in the library project. Now you only need to include the jar-file in the project which is supposed to use ads. I guess the R.bool.paid is not needed now when I'm looking at it again.

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem. Could you explain more as to how you did this? Your activity is in the library project, so wouldnt you still have to include the jar?