# Converting project as a library

Tags: android, android-support-library

I've made a basic project for custom toast. Now I want that project to work as a library in my future projects. How do I convert my project into a library?
P.S: This is just a dummy project so that I can learn how to create libraries of my own. 
The code is as follows:

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom_layout,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();


        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627492/android-library-project

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse

Right Click on **Project --> Properties --> Android** and Check the **Is Library** checkbox

Comment: I know this part. I even checked it as a library project while creating the project. but this project is not working. Try this on your system and tell me if there is a change needed. there are some errors.

Comment: @Apoorv clean your project.

Comment: What project are you talking about?

Comment: @Apoorv please try the above code and tell me what's missing.

Comment: All i see missing is layout files that's because i did not create it

Comment: The layout file only contains a button. Nothing much.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Eclipse? then, 
**project right click->properties->Android->check `Is Library`**(placed in below)

if you are using android studio, 
In your build.gradle file, **use** `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` **not**, `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`